# Pandas DataFrame as lookup table with embedded lists

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
     A          B
    [1, 2, 3] [a, b, c]
    [4, 5, 6] [d, e, f]
```

I want to query the dataframe such that when I input `1`, it should return `[a,b,c]`. Similarly, querying for `6` should return `[d, e, f]`. What's the most readable way to do it?

Comment: Why are you using a dataframe for this? what other features of the dataframe are necessary in a broader context?

Comment: ``df.loc[[ind for ind, colA in zip(df.index, df.A) if n in colA]]``

Comment: I am using a client lib that returns data in df format. I can explode the df but wanted to avoid unnecessary ops

Comment: what a strange format. i guess it takes all kinds in this world

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `map` and `loc`

```
n = 1
df.loc[df.A.map(lambda x: n in x), 'B']

Out[209]:
0    [a, b, c]
Name: B, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I would explode your dataframe:

```py
df = df.explode('A').set_index('A')

n = 1
print(df.loc[n, 'B'])
```

prints:

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: I do not have access to 'explode' (pandas == 0.24)

Comment: I recommend upgrading